# error: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-platform, firmware

Im following [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile) guide to compile bootcode bat Im geting an error

```
mips-linux-xgcc: fatal error: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
```

Even I defined it like so

```
STAGING_DIR=/home/slobodan/Desktop/NETIS/rtk_openwrtSDK_v2.5_20160905/rtk_openwrt_sdk/staging_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `export STAGING_DIR=/...` need to be entered in same shell session